# Can I travel to Hawaii while on my 90 day ESTA?

Tags: usa, esta, hawaii

I’m booked to travel to Hawaii in about two weeks. I know that it is one of the 50 states but am I allowed to travel on an airplane? I’m here till September, but will traveling overseas affect my ESTA?

Answer (score 7):

As you said, Hawaii is one of the 50 states. By flying from one of the other 49 to Hawaii, you are not leaving the US. Such flights to Hawaii are purely domestic. You are not going "overseas" from the perspective of US immigration law. Your ESTA will not be affected or even checked as you would not be passing through US immigration. As long as you have valid ID for the flight and are not out of status, you will be allowed to fly and return.

Comment: Actually, under a strict reading of US immigration law, travel between the contiguous 48 states and Hawaii is the same as travel between the contiguous 48 states and Puerto Rico or the US Virgin Islands.  Yet CBP treats them differently.  The law is a bit confusing, so I'm not sure which approach is correct.  I've [asked about this](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/32510/333) at [Law.SE].  But as a practical matter, this is correct: there are no immigration controls, and there is no exit or entry.  If anyone *does* ask to see Sam's passport, he can just show it.